# Making Form's RealEditControl field editable in Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

In EcoResProductDetailsExtended  (Released Product Details) form, I want to make the Volume as editable which is in Manage Inventory fast tab's Physical Dimensions group.

When this form is opened, it is in non editable mode.

This field should be made editable when Volume is updated in WHSPhysDimUOM (Physical Dimensions) form.

I tried setting the property of the corresponding field in init() method but it's not working.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is only the volume field not editable or are all fields not editable? If the later is the case, you need to change the `ViewEditMode` of the form (see https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/108051).

Comment: The datasource for that field could also be set to not allow editing, in which case you'll have to set it to allow editing, and set all the other fields in the DS to not.